# Running out of heap space

Tags: java, scala, jvm, heap-memory

I am having a heap space problem. My program is simple. There are two actors (send & receive) "send" actor is passing 10000 objects per second to "receive", and receive publishes those objects. the receivers received object is  being saved in the container but the container is being emptied every second. So no chance the container is running out of space. Now after 420000 objects my eclipse shoes an error saying " **ioconsole updater has encountered problem"** . And when i goto into details i see the error **Internal error :: Java heap space**

I have tried increasing the heap size. 
My Heap size is 8096m and maxpermsize is 4096

I am monitoring my code using visualVm and i am noticing that it is not exceeding the heap size atall. Totally blank as how to fix the problem.

Can some one let me know what other possible scenarios can lead to such errors.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

IOConsole is an eclipse class, not your program's. Are you printing to System.out a lot? Under Window > Preferences search for "console". Set some sort of limit for all the console buffers. Try printing less output from the program. Maybe log to a file instead.

Comment: Yea i was not able to find the printf lines because it was done by lagback.xml file. As changed the status in that file the log lines got reduced and the error got reduced. Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 8):

This problem has occured due to the buffer size in console.

Solution :

Right Click the Console -> Preferences

limit the console.

Answer (score 5):

You can add the following JVM args to give you an idea of the memory usage and what the GC is doing:

```
-Xloggc:/tmp/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the problem and I tried to solve it by changing heap and buffer settings in eclipse. However I couldn't solve it. Then I noticed there is a memory leak in my program and the number of threads increase in time. The problem was solved after I had fixed the bug. I think memory leak is not the most probable reason for it but it should be considered.