# how to read from a huge file and write to a new file by java

Tags: java

What I am doing is to read one file line by line, format every line, then write to a new file.  But the problem is that the file is huge, nearly 178 MB.  **But always getting error message: IO console updater error, java heap space.** Here is my code:

```
public class fileFormat {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        String strLine;

        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("train_final.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("newOUTPUT.txt"));

        while((strLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
            List<String> numberBox = new ArrayList<String>();
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(strLine);
            while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
                numberBox.add(st.nextToken());
            }
            for (int i=1; i< numberBox.size(); i++){
                String head = numberBox.get(0);
                String tail = numberBox.get(i);
                String line = head + "  "+tail ;
                System.out.println(line);
                writer.write(line);
                writer.newLine();
            }
            numberBox.clear();
        }
        reader.close();
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

How can I avoid this error message? Moreover, I have set the VM preference: -xms1024m

Comment: You might try flushing the `BufferedWriter`

Comment: @MadProgrammer: That should not cause OOM. The buffer is not that huge.

Comment: How about using RandomAccessFile?

Comment: Looks like it is an eclipse problem. Have a look at this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001252/running-out-of-heap-space

Comment: I would avoid writing to sout

Comment: @Thilo That's what I thought, but I can't see any immediate issue :P

Comment: Probably caused by the fact that you write to system.out the entire file...

Comment: @Gusdor: No way. The buffer has a fixed size, when it's full it will flush by itself.

Comment: Are you certain that your file in question has line separators properly? Otherwise the readLine will go on until running out of memory.

Comment: @Marc Where?  I see `System.out.println(line)`, but that's just a concatenation of local variables...unless it's an issue with Eclipse...

Comment: @MadProgrammer line is the concatenation of head and tail which are elements of numberBox which is populated via a StringTokenizer which take as argument a line of the file, inside a while loop going through the entire file. I think it is actually writting the all file down.

I would be interested to see how this behave without the Sys.out.println() line...

Comment: 178 MB is not that big.  You could read it into memory with one read(bytes) and convert it to one String with the memory you have. (I don't suggest doing that, but really its a trivial size)

Comment: @mac I'd like to see it run from the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the line

```
System.out.println(line);
```

This is a workaround the fialing console updater, which otherwise runs out of memory.

Comment: I reproduced the problem and removing the line solves it. This is an eclipse problem. the code works like a charm without writing to the sysout.

Answer (score 0):

The program looks okay. I suspect the problem is that you run this inside of Eclipse, and System.out is collected by Eclipse in memory (to be displayed in that Console window).

```
 System.out.println(line);
```

Try to run it outside of Eclipse, change Eclipse settings to pipe System.out somewhere, or remove the line.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the code:

```
       for (int i=1; i< numberBox.size(); i++){
            String head = numberBox.get(0);
            String tail = numberBox.get(i);
            String line = head + "  "+tail ;
            System.out.println(line);
            writer.write(line);
            writer.newLine();
       }
```

Can be translated to:

```
       String head = numberBox.get(0);
       for (int i=1; i< numberBox.size(); i++){
            String tail = numberBox.get(i);
            System.out.print(head);
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.println(tail);
            writer.write(head);
            writer.write(" ");
            writer.write(tail);
            writer.newLine();
       }
```

This may add a little code duplication but it avoids creating a lot of objects.

Also there if you merge this for loop with the loop contructing the numberBox, you won't need numberBox structure at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you read whole file the heap memory will occupy so better option in to read the file in chuck. See my below code. It will start reading from the offset given in argument and will return the end offset . You need to pass number of lines to be read.

Please remember: You can use any collection to store these read lines and clear the collection before calling this method to read next chunk.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
InputStreamReader   streamReader = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
LineNumberReader   reader = new LineNumberReader(streamReader);
```

//call this below method recursively until the file does not reaches to the end

```
public int getParsedLines(LineNumberReader reader, int iLineNumber_Start, int iNumberOfLinesToBeRead) {
    int iLineNumber_End = 0;

    int iReadUptoLines = iLineNumber_Start + iNumberOfLinesToBeRead;

    try {
        reader.mark(iLineNumber_Start);
        reader.setLineNumber(iLineNumber_Start);
        do {
            String str = reader.readLine();
            if (str == null) {
                break;
            }
            // your code


            iLineNumber_End = reader.getLineNumber();
        } while (iLineNumber_End != iReadUptoLines);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // exception handling
    }
    return iLineNumber_End;
}
```